# Ruby object allocation type coercion

Tags: ruby

Given this Ruby class (importantly, **not** ActiveRecord or Rails):

```
class Document
  attr_accessor :word_total, :pages

  def initialize
    @pages = []
  end

  def word_total
    @pages.map(&:word_count).sum
  end
end
```

And this line of code in another class:

```
@document.pages << @pages
```

I get this error.

```
Failure/Error: @pages.map(&:word_count).sum

NoMethodError:
undefined method `word_count' for [#<Page:0x00007ff76ca85320  @word_count=254>]:Array
```

How can I coerce the type of collection to be a `Page` instead of an `Array`? Is that the problem I'm experiencing?

Comment: I'll add it, but you can see it inside the array in the error message.

Comment: Your code as shown does not work in the way described. `pages` is defined as an instance variable but it has no getter or setter methods. `Document.new.pages` raises `NoMethodError: undefined method 'pages' for #<Document:0x00007fcd1fb1dbb0 @pages=[]>`. Please make sure your code samples work as described first!

Comment: My bad, I've fixed it. I was simplifying the problem for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
@document.pages << @pages
```

to

```
@document.pages = @pages
```